# Stripe Invoice Line Item Description incorrect

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently working on a project that is using stripe for subscription payments.

The PRO plan has been setup on Stripe at €80,00 per month.
When the invoice appears the description on the invoice's line item is :

1x PRO (@ €0,80)

I expect that it would read something like this "1x PRO  (@ €80,00)"

When I checked the object that has been returned from Stripe then it appears incorrectly there too.

When I checked on the stripe dashboard it looks fine..

Any idea why this is happening and what can be done to ensure that the description on the invoice line item appears properly ?

Kind regards,
Fergal.

[image]

Comment: The charge is stored in cents, are you missing the conversion?.

Comment: I don't think that is it, as the description on the invoice item is a string... i can't convert it unless i parse and update it myself.

Comment: That is almost definitely it.  You'll need to do the conversion from dollars to cents.  Stripe works in the lowest subunit of the currency; meaning when working with euros, you work in cents.  If you show us how you're creating your plan with code, we can probably guide you through how to do the conversion.

Comment: See my update.  The issue is simply in the desc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has simply disappeared.
Perhaps the original invoice was not correctly configured.
Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe somehow supports [zero decimal currency](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal).  read the link for more reference.

You have to create a subscription by multiplying your amount by 100 as amount need to be passed in the smallest unit of currency.

> All API requests expect amounts to be provided in a currency’s
>   smallest unit. For example, to charge $10 USD, provide an amount value
>   of 1000 (i.e, 1000 cents).